# Loops and Statistics. Not printing correct value

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, statistics

I wrote a program that prompts the user to enter 10 grades, and it calculates the sum of the grades, the average of grades, the highest grade, smallest grade and the range between highest and smallest. And then it prints all these things using system.out.print.

My problem is that everything works EXCEPT for the highest value. Here is my code.

> int x = 10;
>       int i = 1;
>       int sum = 0;
>       int guess = 100;
>       int max = 100;

```
while (i <= 10) {
x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter one grade at a time."));
i++;
sum+=x;

if(x<guess){
   guess = x;
    }
if(x>max){
    max = x;

} 

}
System.out.println("The sum of your grades is " + sum);
System.out.println("The average of your grades is " + (sum/10));
System.out.println("The smallest grade is " +guess);
System.out.println("The highest grade is " +max);
System.out.println("The range of your grades is " + (max-guess));
```

Lets say the 10 numbers entered are 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,99 it will print saying "The highest grade is 100" but 100 wasn't entered. It always says 100. How can I fix this? Thank you!!

Comment: Consider using [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `max` to be **0** instead of 100:

```
int max = 0;
```

You're initially setting `max` to 100. Which means that at the end of the last iteration (where x is equal to 99), this condition

```
if(x > max)
```

would be `false`.

*(Notice how 100 is greater than any of the numbers that you use in your test sample. If there was a number greater than 100 included, this wouldn't have been the case, & your code would seem to work.)*

Comment: Wow what a simple fix, haha, thank you!! Will accept answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you initialized max with 100, so it will always be greater than x and not changed. Change the declaration of max to be zero and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because in initial variable int max = 100; you put the default value as 100(maximum), so compiler checks if the value entered is less than 100, which is as default. It is no. so max variable keeps value 100 as always, unless higher input is in